# Backwards slash not accepted in Visual Studio connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

I cannot connect to SQL Server from Visual Studio because the server name contains characters that Visual Studio will not accept. The backslash `\` is causing the problem.

I can connect using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I tried installing a second instance of SQL Server on my pc but I cannot give the server a unique name that I choose.

I tried changing the server name as well using SQL commands I found online but then I could not connect to SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio and I reinstalled SQL-Server because of this.

Anybody ever experienced this? If so how did you resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

PS: this is the server name `DESKTOP-J6AO2D4\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Why wont it accept it?  What error are you getting?  Did you try escaping the backslashes?

Comment: By the way, the server name is `DESKTOP-J6AO2D4` the *instance* name is `SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are connecting from C# to SQL Server you should use a [verbatim string literal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-verbatim-string-literal/)

i.e. the **@** prefix below.

```
var connection = @"....DESKTOP-J6AO2D4\SQLEXPRESS....."
```

Comment: Double slashes as mentioned by the other answers should work too.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried using double backward slash like this
"DESKTOP-J6AO2D4\\SQLEXPRESS"